# SQL Date and Flash Date problem

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, air

I am using the local database feature in AIR 1.5. I have a table which is created by:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (timeAdded Date, name STRING)"
```

Now lets say that I want every employee added between `date1:Date` and `date2:Date`, I would do that by using:

```
"SELECT * FROM employees WHERE " + date1 + "<timeAdded AND timeAdded<" + date2
```

This does not work, because the type `Date` in SQL is a [Julian day number (JDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), and `date1` and `date2` are flash formatted dates. It is not possible to get the JDN of a date through flash. How do I solve the problem?

**Edit:** I did not find solution to this problem, but I used the Date.time function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not the result of not having quotes around the dates?

Try:
`"SELECT * FROM employees WHERE '" + date1 + "'<timeAdded AND timeAdded<'" + date2+"'"`

Otherwise, is there no flash "ToString" method or something for dates?

I found the 'formatted to string' that you want.  You are looking for the `DateFormatter` class, which is apparently (unfortunately) a separate download: http://www.yapiodesign.com/blog/2005/11/10/dateformatter-static-class-update-of-darron-schalls-dateformatas/

ALSO: have you looked into the "DateUtil" classes?

Finally: Someone who had the same problem, and solved it: http://blog.wheelerstreet.com/a-quick-actionscript-3-workaround-for-ms-sql

Comment: I have tried added the '' but without luck. The `ToString` method does not return a Julian Day Number, it returns a string in the format "Thu Oct 8 15:06:07 2009 UTC"

Comment: Check out the last few things, the last link has someone who had a similar problem, the DateFormatter and DateUtil classes are described in that last link, and contain functions to help.

Comment: I think you got it wrong, when you call toString() in flash it returns the format "Thu Oct 8 15:06:07 2009 UTC". I need a Julian Day Number.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the answer in the future:

```
sqlStatement.text = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE :date1 < timeAdded AND timeAdded < :date2"
sqlStatement.parameters[":date1"] = date1;
sqlStatement.parameters[":date2"] = date2;
```

This should work.